# JavaFX getChartChildren() from a Class other than Chart

Tags: java, javafx

How can I accomplish the command below from a class that does not extend Chart?

```
getChartChildren().get(0).setMouseTransparent(true); // child is plotBackground
```

The method `getChartChildren()` is protected in Chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options: let your class extend Cart or move your class to the same packaga as the Cart class.

Comment: Any option that is not with the obvious, maybe in Chart class?